# what logic should be used to create a lock screen like in angry birds

Tags: java, android, andengine, sprite

i am developing a game like angry birds in which i am using a lock screen in which first round is by default open to play but another 9 rounds are locked 
now i want to know to create an activity to unlock these rounds when completing rounds

i thaught to write score in a file then make 2nd round to read that file if text file contains score 100 then next round should b open but i am not going to use this technique because when i run activity for the first time it gives me error that file not found because without playing file wont  create...
is there any solution for this

```
 public final static String STORETEXT = "round2.txt";
  if (mScore == 100) {
        int a =1;
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    openFileOutput(STORETEXT, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE));
            out.write(new Integer(a).toString());
            out.close();
        } catch (Throwable t) {

        }
```

on another side in lockscreen

```
  ImageButton i1, i2;
 try {
        fis = openFileInput("round2.txt");
        BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        strLine = null;

        if ((strLine = d.readLine()) != null) {
            d.close();
            fis.close();

        }

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(),
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

int B = Integer.parseInt(strLine);

if(B==1){

    i2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lockopen));
            i2.setClickable(true);

}
else{
    i2.setClickable(false);
    i2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lockclose));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my view you don't have to use text file for any of the purpose in game development. Either you have to use database or shared preferences.

This thing well discussed in following websites

1. http://www.matim-dev.com/data-storage.html
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: i dnt have any idea about shared preferences can u give me any example how this can be done using shared prefernces.

Comment: If you look through second link you found suitable example in it. If you want store small amount of storage of data then only use shared preference otherwise prefer to use database.